# Offline-directline: My webchat app keeps sending GET requests to /directline/conversations/ endpoint. Is this normal?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I had a local bot which I wanted to test in WebChat client instead of Emulator. After researching for a while and failing to connect normally, I stumbled upon a package called offline-directline which helped me connect my local bot successfully. My directline runs on 4000, webchat runs on 3000 and local bot runs on 3979.

I took a peak in the network tab later and I see my client keeps making GET requests to /directline/conversations/ endpoint. At first I thought it happens when I am sending messages in my WebChat client but it keeps sending them repeatedly. Around 50 GET requests in a minute.

[image]

I am not sure if this is a normal behavior. Would really appreciate an input. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your webchat client code? I have the offline directline and bot running locally and I tried a few samples for the webchat client but unable to get the web chat running.

Comment: Sorry @Andy, I cannot do that. It's corporate. But I'd be glad to have a look at your code and help you figure out the missing piece.